# Encrypt and Decrypt Password in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, security, ios5, ios6

I want to encrypt password in iOS.

```
NSData *dataIn = [@"Now is the time for all good computers to come to the aid of their masters." dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSMutableData *macOut = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CC_SHA256(dataIn.bytes, dataIn.length,  macOut.mutableBytes);

NSLog(@"dataIn: %@", dataIn);
NSLog(@"macOut: %@", macOut);
```

I want to create with a specified key. Is there any way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use SHA256. Bcrypt or PBKDF2. SHA256 is too weak. Encrypt the data with the hash, and don't store it for comparison, always generate from user input.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If can use NSString you can download NSString Additions.

Good Tutorial [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130116155209/http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/create-md5-hash-from-nsstring-nsdata-or-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're actually not encrypting your string only hashing using SHA2.
To encrypt using a real key you should use CCCrypt() for actual encrypting.

I suggest looking at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CCCrypt.3cc.html

Answer (score -1):

Encryption and decryption using OpenSSL library:
https://github.com/zeeshankhan/ZKOpenSSLPlay